# createElement in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with CreateElemant in JavaScript this is my code:

```
function generateInputs()
{
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    for(var j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        var c = document.createElement("input");
        var r = document.createElement("input");
        r.setAttribute('type',"radio");
        document.getElementById('questions').appendChild(r);
        c.setAttribute('type',"input");
        document.getElementById('questions').appendChild(c);
    }

    i.setAttribute('type',"text");

    document.getElementById('questions').appendChild(i);

}
```

And I want to write it with jQuery but I didn't find an equivalent for **createElement**()

Comment: This code is already jQuery compatible because jQuery is written in JavaScript.

Comment: `jQuery('<input />')` creates a new `input` element and returns its jQuery object reference

Comment: $('<div />'); you need this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try with:

```
function generateInputs()
{
    var i = $('<input type="text"/>');

    for(var j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        var c = $('<input type="text"/>');
        var r = $('<input type="radio"/>');

        $('#questions').append(c).append(r);
    }


    $('#questions').append(i);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// $("#id"), $("element") or $(".class") for selecting parent


$("#foo").append("<div>hello world</div>")

var txt1="<p>Text.</p>";               // Create element with HTML  
var txt2=$("<p></p>").text("Text.");   // Create with jQuery
var txt3=document.createElement("p");  // Create with DOM
txt3.innerHTML="Text.";
$("p").append(txt1,txt2,txt3);         // Append the new elements
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation ?

Comment: sure see the comments on right 3 ways of creating a element after creation just append these to the tag inside which you wanna insert it

Answer (score 1):

Are you just wanting to create new elements on the fly? If so this should do what you need:

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'foo',
    name: 'bar'
}).appendTo('#questions');
```

Obviously change the "type", and "name" to whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<input />').attr('type','radio').appendTo(document.body)
```

some like that

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fHZ9V/)</kbd>

```
function generateInputs() {
    var i = $("<input/>"); //var i = document.createElement("input");
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var c = $("<input/>", { //document.createElement("input");
            type: "radio" //r.setAttribute('type',"radio");
        });
        var r = $("<input/>", { //document.createElement("input");
            type: "radio" //c.setAttribute('type',"radio");
        });
        $('#questions').append(r);//document.getElementById('questions').appendChild(r);
        $('#questions').append(c);//document.getElementById('questions').appendChild(c);
    }
    i.attr('type', "text"); // i.setAttribute('type',"text");
    $('#questions').append(i);//document.getElementById('questions').appendChild(i);
}
```

---

A little shorter code

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fHZ9V/1)</kbd>

```
function generateInputs() {
    var i = $("<input/>", {
        type: "text"
    });
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var c = $("<input/>", {
            type: "radio"
        });
        var r = $("<input/>", {
            type: "radio"
        });
        $('#questions').append(r, c);
    }
    $('#questions').append(i);
}
```

---

[Learn jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com)

[jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateInputs() {
    var i = $('<input type="text"');
    for ( var j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
        var c = $('<input type="input" />');
        var r = $('<input type="radio" />');
        $('#questions').append(r).append(c);
    }
    $(document).append(i);
}
```